is there a way to rewrite how touch events are handled in windows 10/11 to better emulate mouse control?
Touch screens under win10/11 behave in ways that mess up apps designed for mice (mostly games). WM_BUTTON_DOWN messages are sent .2 ms before WM_BUTTON_UP messages, which cause many games to miss that WM_BUTTON_DOWN happened at all.  And the long click / double finger trick for right clicking often just gets treated as a single click or two clicks right next to each other.
I've been experimenting with low-level mouse hooks to convert touch events into mouse events better suited to games, but before I can do anything fancy I'm stuck on the simplest of problems, preventing touch events from making events that bypass the WH_MOUSE_LL hook. Here's a simple example which eats all lefts clicks (and forms the skeleton of the code that converts them to right clicks instead).
// After registration this gets called by windows for every mouse event (movement + clicks)
LRESULT WINAPI MyMouseCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{


if (wParam==WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
    // todo: send right click down instead, eg MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN
    return -1;
    }

if (wParam==WM_LBUTTONUP)
    {
    // todo: send MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP 
    return -1;
    }


return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam); 
// return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.
}

This code works perfectly when just using the mouse; no left clicks get thru, and with the proper SendInput calls I can make all left clicks work as right clicks . But as soon as you try it on a touch screen it all falls apart; screen taps result in messages that apps like windows explorer interpret as left clicks, and games also think that left clicks are happening.
I'm not the first person to try this approach, for the same reasons:
https://github.com/blamarche/TouchGamingMouse
His code is poorly documented as is the proper setup of necessary external tools (AHK) so the fact that it doesn't work isn't completely informative, but looking at his code it also uses the LowLevelMouseProc hook, so maybe this worked in much older versions of windows but not now?
So is there any path forward? Maybe an invisible touch screen event eating window on top of all others that takes each touch event and then makes new mouse events for the next app in the z-order? this might work for desktop/windowed apps but seems unlikely to work for fullscreen apps (aka games).

You may need this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/windows-touch-portal. Windows supports touch input. Fine-grained gesture interpretation or custom handling of multiple touch points might meet your requirement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/choosing-the-right-approach-to-windows-touch#you-want-fine-grained-gesture-interpretation-or-custom-handling-of-multiple-touch-points

@Torrecto-MSFT only the topmost window can get touch events though, so that's the route to take only if some kind of transparent overlay can be put on top of everything.

I'm back from vacation. I have checked the link from github. Have you seen that？It usesd GetMessageExtraInfo to determine whether to use touch input or pen input in DisableTouchConversionToMouse.cs. You need to do the same thing to call GetMessageExtraInfo to get the message source before using mouse hook.

And the problem of switching to the topmost window can be overcome: Alt+Tab.

@Torrecto-MSFT how does GetMessageExtraInfo help? I think you are confused, it only helps sort events that are already delivered to the hook.

NO! It is necessary. It is a key to determine whether the current message is from a mouse click or a touch in the mouse message. Or use RegisterTouchWindow to register the window as a Touch window. Now It does not convert to mouse messages by default.

Simplily, the program you're using now is modifying mouse message, not a touch message. The touch gesture has its default corresponding mouse message:  https://i.sstatic.net/AFiJz.png

Sure, but if I block all messages delivered to the hook, the touch events still come thru. So filtering fewer messages isn't going to help.

It doesn't prevent it from being converted to a traditional mouse message by default. Use RegisterTouchWindow to register the window as a Touch window. Now it may block the hook message.
